# Batch insert of array data into mysql database using objection.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, knex.js, objection.js

I have an array

```
newData = [{ sId: 'XXXXXX', itemlName: 'LSｽﾄﾚｯ', iCode: 'XXXXXX', iType: '', skus: 'XXXXXXX', iLevel: 'L2', cCode: '88', cName: 'Other', sCode: '999', sName: 'No Control', pLengthCode: '988', core: 'N', sCode: '1', dCode: 'XX', gDeptCode: 'XX', gDeptName: 'Women\\\'s Items', rCode: 'jqs' },{ sId: 'XXXXXX', itemlName: 'LSｽﾄﾚｯ', iCode: 'XXXXXX', iType: '', skus: 'XXXXXXX', iLevel: 'L2', cCode: '88', cName: 'Other', sCode: '999', sName: 'No Control', pLengthCode: '988', core: 'N', sCode: '1', dCode: 'XX', gDeptCode: 'XX', gDeptName: 'Women\\\'s Items', rCode: 'jqs' }]
```

I wants to insert `newData` in to mysql database using objection.js. But when I run my node application , I got the error saying:

> Error: batch insert only works with Postgresql

My insert code is -:

```
samplemodel.query().insert( newData );
```

How can I perform the batch insertion of array data in mysql data base using objection.js?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Error: batch insert only works with Postgresql

Well, that means that you need Postgres's instead of Mysql to make it work.

Edit1:

From the docs:

> If you are using Postgres the inserts are done in batches for maximum
>   performance. On other databases the rows need to be inserted one at a
>   time. This is because postgresql is the only database engine that
>   returns the identifiers of all inserted rows and not just the first or
>   the last one.

That means that if you are using mysql you should do

```
samplemodel.query().insert(data);
```

For each element in the "newData" array.

Comment: Sorry, but this is not an answer to the question.

Comment: Why not? It seemed to help the OP

Comment: Because your answer doesn't solve the problem, which is: Insert in batch USING MySQL. The OP specified Mysql as a tag.

Comment: The docs state that its NOT posible to insert batch using MySQL, so the only solution is to insert them one by one.

Answer (score 7):

You can call

`samplemodel.query().insertWithRelated( newData );`

which uses multiple queries if needed and works with all databases.

Answer (score 4):

#### In latest version of Objection `insertWithRelated` Deprecated!

Instead you need to use `insertGraph`

```js
samplemodel.query().insertGraph(newData);
```

or

```js
samplemodel.query().insertGraph(newData, { allowRefs: true });
```

Answer (score 3):

Hence there is no way to reduce number of queries, due to mysql limitations.

I would loop over it insert it into array of promises and execute it throw `Promise.all`

```
...
let insertPromises = []
for(let item of newData){
    insertPromises.push(samplemode.query().insert(item))
}

Promise.all(insertPromises).then(() => { ... })
...
```

I would suggest using transactions if I'm using this approach with `$query` or `$relatedQuery` to ensure data integerity

Comment: could you give an example of transaction with promise.all?

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to make the convert the insert statement into a string and execute the raw sql.

Something like

`let insertQuery = samplemodel.query().insert( newData );
let insertRes = await knex.raw(insertQuery.toString())`

PS: if this is not good practice, I'd appreciate you letting me know!